# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, webservice, slim3

Estoy intentando actualizar un objeto de mi `bd` a traves de mi `API`, estoy utilizando `Slim Framework 3` pero cuando ejecuto el `postman` me tira el siguiente error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

```
<?php

    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;    

    $app->group('/persona/', function () {

        $app = new \Slim\App;   

        $this->put('editar/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

            $input = json_decode($request->getBody());
            $array = (array)$input;
            $nombre = $array['nombre']; 
            $apellido = $array['apellido']; 
            $id = $array['id'];

            $sql = "UPDATE persona SET nombre=:nombre, apellido=:apellido, id=:id WHERE id=$id";

            try {   
                $db = new db();
                $db = $db->connect();

                $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
                $sth->bindParam('nombre', $nombre);
                $sth->bindParam('apellido', $apellido);
                $sth->bindParam('id', $id);

                $sth->execute();
                $db = null;

                echo '{"notice": {"text": "Persona Actualizada"}';

            } catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage(). '}';

            }

        });

    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Estás accediendo mal a los datos enviados desde el formulario, y también estás bindiando los datos incorrectamente, según [La Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) deberías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
 <?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;


$app->group('/persona/', function () {

    $app = new \Slim\App;

    $this->put('editar/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

        $nombre = $request->getAttribute('nombre');
        $apellido = $request->getAttribute('apellido');
        $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

        $input = json_decode($request->getBody());

        $sql = "UPDATE persona SET nombre=:nombre, apellido=:apellido, id=:id WHERE id=$id";

        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam('nombre', $nombre);
        $sth->bindParam('apellido', $apellido);
        $sth->bindParam('id', $id);


        $sth->execute();
        return $this->response->withJson($input);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Al llamar a:

```
$input = json_decode($request->getBody());
```

El objeto devuelto depende del `json` que pasas a la función `json_decode`. Si el `json` es algo como lo siguiente:

```
{
    "param1" : 1,
    "param2" : 2,
    "param3" : 3,
    "param4" : 4
}
```

Te devolverá un objeto de tipo `stdClass`. Por lo tanto, suponiendo que los datos a los que intentas acceder sean correctos y se encuentren en el `string` de `$request->getBody()`, debes acceder a ellos de esta forma:

```
$sth->bindParam($nombre, $input->nombre);
$sth->bindParam($apellido, $input->apellido);
$sth->bindParam($id, $input->id);
```

Pero si quieres manetener tu código como lo tienes, puedes pasar `true` como segundo parámetro de `json_decode` y entonces el objeto que obtendrás será de tipo `array` porque te devolverá un `array` asociativo.

```
$input = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
```

De esta manera sí puedes acceder así:

```
$sth->bindParam($nombre, $input['nombre']);
$sth->bindParam($apellido, $input['apellido']);
$sth->bindParam($id, $input['id']);
```

De todas maneras no sé de dónde quieres sacar estos datos, si de `$request->getBody()` o  de las variables que obtienes con `$request->getAttribute`, ya eso dependerá de tu implementación.

Comment: efectivamente el `json` que le paso a la funcion es el mismo q muestro en la imagen. He realizado las modificaciones correspondientes para el caso de `$input = json_decode($request->getBody());` como `$input = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);` pero en ambos casos me devuelve error, y he identificado que si hago un `var_dump($nombre);` luego de `$nombre = $request->getAttribute('nombre');`devuelve `NULL`

Comment: @Germanccho, he visto ahora la actualización de tu código. Si has situado `true` como segundo parámetro de `json_decode`  no necesitas hacer un `cast` de `array`, accede a los datos directamente. Por otro lado, algo que te mencionaba en un anterior comentario, ¿Por qué declaras la variable `$app` dentro del método `group`? ¿no deberías tenerla declarada desde antes?